# Visualizar quantidades de colunas em cada tabela

Tags: mysql, tabela-banco-de-dados, phpmyadmin

Como eu faço para o phpmyadmin me mostrar isso:

```
--- tabelas ---

usuarios(5)
clientes(20)
admins(2)
```

por exemplo usando algum comando mysql ou até mesmo alguma funcionalidade do phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para visualizar as tabelas de um determinado Banco no Mysql com a quantidade de colunas utilize a SQL logo abaixo:

*Obs: '**generics**' é o nome do Banco*, então troque para o nome do seu banco

```
SELECT a.TABLE_NAME,
       a.TABLE_SCHEMA, 
       (SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.COLUMNS b
            WHERE b.TABLE_SCHEMA = a.TABLE_SCHEMA and b.TABLE_NAME = a.TABLE_NAME)
       TABLE_COLUMNS_COUNT  
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES a        
WHERE a.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' and a.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'generics'
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outra seria com Group By (*Obs: vai trazer as views também*)

```
SELECT  b.TABLE_NAME,
        b.TABLE_SCHEMA,
        count(b.TABLE_SCHEMA) TABLE_COLUMNS_COUNT
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS b
WHERE b.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'generics'
GROUP BY b.TABLE_SCHEMA, b.TABLE_NAME
```

Fonte: [Clique aqui](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html)

Comment: Boa resposta, é isso mesmo Obrigado..

Comment: Vlw @SilvioAndorinha

Answer (score 2):

No PHPMyAdmin basta você selecionar o banco de dados e clicar no (**+**) e ele irá expandir e exibir todas as tabelas do banco selecionado, se licar novamente no (**+**) ao lado da tabela, irá exibir os campos dela. Veja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso queria fazer via MySQL, utilize o comando SHOW TABLES, como o amigo **NULL** já respondeu:

```
SHOW TABLES FROM database;
```

@edit

Você também quer fazer uma contagem de registros de cada tabela, é isso mesmo? Se for, utilize o comando abaixo:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_ROWS FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'seu_database'
```

Comment: Boa resposta mas ele me trouxe a quantidade de registro em cada tabela e eu quero saber a quantidade de coluna.. mas mesmo assim valeu