# Contar as colunas de uma tabela do MySQL usando PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Como posso contar as colunas de uma tabela do MySQL usando PHP, alguém conhece algum comando para fazer isso?

Eu tentei fazer assim mas não deu certo:

```
$sql4 = mysql_query("show fields from ".$tabela) or die('erro na query');
$rows4=mysql_fetch_array($sql4);
$total=count($rows4);
```

Comment: Lembrando que o uso da função `mysql_query()` **não** é recomendado devido a vários motivos relacionados a segurança. Utilize [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) ou [Mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php) no lugar.

Comment: Existe essa resposta também: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13092/visualizar-quantidades-de-colunas-em-cada-tabela/13101#13101

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para contar as **colunas** de uma tabela:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_schema = 'nome_da_sua_base_de_dados' AND
table_name = 'nome_da_sua_tabela';
```

[Exemplo no SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/26859)

Comment: Desculpe amigo, eu alterei aki é funcionou, resolveu o meu problema! obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, você pode usar o comando:

[pg_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.pg-num-rows.php)

```
 * Retorna o numero de linhas dessa consulta
 * 
 * 
 * @return  Integer : Numero de linhas da consulta
```

ou se for um update pode usar essa:

[pg_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.pg-affected-rows.php)

```
 * Retorna o numero de linhas alteradas por essa consulta
 * 
 * 
 * @return  Integer : Numero de linhas  alteradas
```

Comment: vlw! é mais uma forma para resolver este problema! nesse caso posso fazer uma consulta e depois usar esse comando para pegar o numero de registros da consulta né?

Comment: pg_* são funções para o postgres, isso não vai retornar o número de colunas de uma tabela do mysql.

Comment: Desculpe, não tinha visto que usas mySQL, porem tem função semelhante. Essas funções são usadas após realizar a consulta.

Comment: sem problemas, toda informação é válida, se não me serviu hoje pode servir amanhã! vlw!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o show columns,

```sql
show columns from my_table;
```

e depois contar as linhas do resultado ...